# How to bind UICollectionView to its controller class?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

On one of the tab bars of my app I want to have `UICollectionView`. Controller for that tab view is `UIViewController`. Additionally on the same view I plan to have UIView on top of UICollectionView.

So I created UICollectionView in storyboard in the UIView of corresponding tab view, also created my class derived from `UICollectionViewController`. But I am not sure how to bind it(UICollectionViewController derived class) to UICollectionView in storyboard.

Comment: You can declare an IB of UICollection and attach the same to that specific UIViewController.

Comment: But I don't want to attach UICollectionView to UIViewController. I want to attach it to my UICollectionViewController, just like I would create a separate UICollectionViewController from object list in storyboard and change its class.

Comment: My best guess is that I have to bind `UICollectionView`'s delegate to my `UICollectionViewController` derived class, but how? Do I have to create property of UICollectionViewController in my UIViewController class, then bind UICollectionView delegate to it?

Comment: If you declare IB variable in UIViewController class then you can either do it programmatically in UIViewController or using story board.

Comment: I've created IB of `UICollectionView` in `UIViewController` and in viewDidLoad a) created instance of `UICollectionViewController` class b) assigned `UICollectionView` delegate to that class. `UICollectionViewController` class is neither calling viewDidLoad, nor `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView`.

Comment: I also assigned `UICollectionViewController`'s .view to outlet of `UICollectionView`. Still no good.

Comment: UIViewController has UICollectionView in it then you can declare an IB variable of UICollectionView and assign it using storyboard. The UICollectionView delegate methods are written inside UIViewController. Hope you are using like this. I have used in one of my project like this.

Comment: OK thanks, you can make it as an answer so I can accept it, if you want.

Comment: Thanks and glad that you could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the same if you have screen layout as UIViewController has UICollectionView in it then you can declare an IB variable of UICollectionView and assign it using storyboard. The UICollectionView delegate methods are written inside UIViewController.

Hope you are using like this. I have used in one of my project like this.